# MongoDB - how to best achieve active/active configuration?

Tags: mongodb

I have an application which is very low on writes. I'm therefore interested in deploying a mongo installation which maximizes the read throughput for the hardware I have (3 database servers in one location). I don't really care for redundancy (backups), but would like automatic failover. Additionally, I'm fine with "eventual consistency", and don't mind if data which isn't the latest data is returned.

I've looked into both sharding and replica sets, and as far as I can tell, I don't really need to use sharding as its benefits suit more for applications with many writes.
I therefore went ahead and installed a replica set on the three servers I have, and I then set the reading preference to "Nearest", as that would allow reads to take place on any server.

The problem is, I later read that the client is "sticky" and basically once it has chosen a "nearest" mongo server, it's not likely to change it. Besides, even if it were to "check for nearest" again, it'll probably choose the same one over. This pretty much results in an active/passive configuration, without any load-balancing. I do have two application servers, so if they choose different mongo servers, it might work ok, but say I wanted to have more than 3 mongo servers in the replica set, then any servers besides specific two would be passive.

Basically my question is, what's the best way to have an active/active configuration for my deployment? All I want is for requests to go to free mongo servers rather than busy ones.

One way to force this which I thought of is to create three sharded-clusters (each server participating in all three), where each server is the primary in one of these clusters - but this is still not optimal, because besides the relative complexity involved in this configuration, this also doesn't guarantee complete load balancing (for example, in case all requests at a given moment happen to go to one specific shard).

What's the right way to achieve what I want? If it's not possible to achieve this kind of load balancing with mongo, would you recommend that I go with the sharded-clusters solution?

Comment: it's not true that it always chooses the same nearest.  it will *randomly* choose from all the servers that are without 15ms of "nearest".

Comment: please note that replicas don't really "scale" reads as each of them has the full database and all the indexes.  If you shard then each of the shards has 1/3 of the db and 1/3 of the indexes - making each read possibly a lot faster.

Comment: why have 1/3 of the db and not 100% of it on each server? the latter would give 100% chance for load balancing while the first depends on what the documents that are read. or am i missing something?

Comment: and about choosing randomly - it says here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-behavior-requests that it indeed chooses randomly but then: "Once the application selects a member of the set to use for read operations, the driver continues to use this connection for read preference until the application specifies a new read preference or something interrupts the connection"

Comment: If you have 3TB of data would you rather keep 3TB on each server or just 1TB? If your indexes are too big to fit in RAM they won't fit in RAM on any of your three replica nodes. Sharding is about splitting up the load to get larger combined capacity.  As far as nearest-random - I'm presuming your application is not single threaded

Comment: the data i have is limited and can fit the disk of one machine. however your point about RAM is something i indeed haven't considered, and is indeed a big plus for sharding.
about nearest-random, my application is indeed not single-threaded, but i am using a single client object for all threads - is that bad practice?

Comment: that should be fine - the driver will take care of handling connection pooling for them - my point was that different threads will bind to different "random" secondary.

Comment: yes I understand, thank you for your help!
(You can write it as a reply rather than a comment if you wish for me to accept your answer)

Answer (score 3):

As you already suspected, scaling reads is not a "one size fits all" problem.  Everything will depend on your data, your access patterns, your requirements and probably a few other things only you can determine.

In a nutshell, the main thing to consider is *why* a single server can't handle your read load.  If it's because of the size of your data set and the size of your indexes then sharding your data across three shards will reduce the RAM requirements of each of them (or to put it another way will give you the combined RAM of all three systems).  As long as you pick a good shard key (one that will distribute the load approximately evenly across all the systems) you will get almost three times the throughput on targeted queries.

If the main requirement for your reads is to reduce as much as possible the latency of reading the data, then a replica set can serve your purposes well as reading from the "nearest" node will reduce the network round-trip time without changing the duration of the operation on the MongoDB server.  This assumes that your writes are infrequent enough or that your application has tolerance of possibly stale data.